# Accessing File Located in Sharepoint List

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365, csom

I'm trying to upload a file from my app web to a sharepoint list, but I'm having some issues when attempting to open/read the file with a filestream.

My code:

```
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead
("https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/appweb/document-library/fileFolder/image.png"))
    {
        var folder = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Images").RootFolder;

        FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
        fileInfo.ContentStream = stream;

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
        fileInfo.Url = "image.png";

        folder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

So I build the `uploadFilePath` variable using `spContext.SPAppWebUrl.ToString();` which assigns the value of the app web to a variable which along with a hardcoded file path and user input for the filename make up my location of the file I want to upload.

The only issue is that when I get to the point of opening my file,  `using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/appweb/document-library/fileFolder/image.png"))` there's an issue due to the semicolon in "https://....." in my app web url being an illegal character.

Is there any way I can access the file without using a full url? I did try trim the "https://" from my url but I think the sharepoint context expects a secure connection and I get an access denied error.

Comment: Could you please instead of parameters to methods use constant values in your sample code? Right now comment "opening my file, using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(uploadFilePath)) there's an issue due to the semicolon in "https://....."  is very confusing as it is not clear which of the variables is set to "https://..." (assuming you are talking about `fileUrl` as otherwise it would make no sense, but good to check anyway).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov No problems, is that easier to understand?

Comment: Thanks for update - now it is clear that you are using wrong method or argument to open file - check out documentation for `File.OpenRead` - it opens local files only. Now it is unclear whether you use wrong source path or wrong method to get file's stream - you'll likely find answer yourself, if not - update question with that info.

Comment: Great, thank you for pointing that out. I managed to find some information on System.Net.WebRequest() which I think will do what I want it to do. If you want to pop that in an answer I'll mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong method or argument to open file - check out documentation for `File.OpenRead` - it opens local files only.

You either need to read stream using HTTP methods (like WebClient/WebRequest) or upload local file.